# Dropping Constraints and then dropping table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This might sound simple to you, but not for first time when you write

I have a query to drop all the constraints in a table using the below query

```
SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

So if this is succesfull (all constraints removed) I need to drop all tables.

Else show valid error message watever the constraint query throwed.

How can I add the conditions in above scenario?

Comment: what is the error or what issue are you facing?

Comment: Why not just append your "drop" statement to the end of `@sql`? If any of the prior statements fail, the drop will fail anyway due to the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Agree @SimonMcKenzie just want to know how i can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `TRY....CATCH`, also you need to initilize your variable @sql. You may also consider to raise your error.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = ''
SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM sys.foreign_keys;
BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage         NVARCHAR(4000)

    DECLARE @ErrorState           INT

    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity        INT 
    --Obtain the error message, severity and state

    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

    --RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

END CATCH
```

If you want to drop tables right after foreign key constraints are removed.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @sqlToDropTables nvarchar(max)
set @sqlToDropTables=''
set @sql = ''

SELECT @sqlToDropTables +=N' DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
                                          + '.'
                                          + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) 
                                          + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToDropTables
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage         NVARCHAR(4000)          
    DECLARE @ErrorState           INT          
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity        INT 
    --Obtain the error message, severity and state      
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()      
    --RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)         
END CATCH
```

Add more code, if you want to clean up all tables, include referenced object, which is the PK tables.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @sqlToDropTables nvarchar(max)
set @sqlToDropTables=''
set @sql = ''

SELECT @sqlToDropTables +=N' DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
                                          + '.'
                                          + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) 
                                          + ';'
                                          + 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id))
                                                          + '.'
                                                          + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)) 
                                                          + ';'

FROM sys.foreign_keys;

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToDropTables
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage         NVARCHAR(4000)          
    DECLARE @ErrorState           INT          
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity        INT 
    --Obtain the error message, severity and state      
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()      
    --RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)         
END CATCH
```

Comment: why do have 2 Drop Table here @Iijh

Comment: parent_object_id is not correct way to fetch all Table Details